# IIS 8 Bad Request 400. request too long

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, iis, http-headers

I have an internal web site that is using windows authentication and just one user is receiveng the **Bad Request Message**. I've set the **MaxFieldLength** and  **MaxRequestBytes** registry keys to their max values without any luck. Also I've set up a custom header: Content-type to 64kb and did not work either.

Any other ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The url maybe too long if you do GET request with many (or long) parameters

Comment: The error shows up at the time the user hits the site. For what I've reading this has to do with kerberos authentication. The user belongs to too many active directory groups causing the kerberos token increase its size the token is send to the server inside the WWW-Authenticate header what causes the request be too long